# Security of HOTP over an unencrypted channel for controling an actuator

Tags: transport-security, hotp

I have a simple on/off actuator that I want to control remotely. I want to use available hardware: a pair of microcontrollers connected to a pair of wireless transceiver modules.

Can [HOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) algorithm be used over an unencrypted channel securely?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "HOTP used securely"?

Comment: @SEJPM My proposal is equivalent to [rolling code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_code) so it has the same weakness: replay attacks. Another example of the maxima do not roll your own crypto.

Answer (score 1):

> Can HOTP algorithm be used over an unencrypted channel securely?

**Yes.**

Essentially, HOTP is a stateful function that keeps an internal counter and then computes an HMAC over that counter followed by some truncations to get the right format. In the process the counter is also incremented.

So assuming we can model [HMAC as a PRF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/578) then the output of each HOTP query is freshly random and unrelated because that's what a random function would do with distinct inputs (and that's how HMAC behaves because it's a PRF). This in particular means that an adversary cannot predict anything about future HMAC outputs or about past unseen outputs.

Of course the only guarantee you get from this is that an adversary cannot predict new authentication tokens and that new tokens likely won't be valid ever again. In particular HOTP by itself does not protect you from things like [relay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay_attack) or attacks where the adversary buffers a token and sends it later at a more convenient time.

Comment: What about [Rolljam vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_code#Rolljam_vulnerability)? An attacker can jam the communication channel until the victim sends 2 or more tokens, store all of them and resend the first one.

Comment: @user3368561 indeed a straight-forward use of HOTP does not prevent this attack.